# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить анимацию существующего круга в этот код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, анимация

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


win= Tk()
win.geometry("700x250")

img = np.ones((1400, 1400, 3))

def drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = abs(x2 - x1)
    dy = abs(y2 - y1)
    
    if x1 < x2:
        xs = 1
    else:
        xs =- 1
        
    if y1 < y2:
        ys = 1
    else:
        ys =- 1
        
    x = x1
    y = y1
    
    if dx > dy:
        p = 2 * y - dx
        
        while x != x2:
            x = x + xs
            if p > 0:
                y = y + ys
                p = p + 2*dy - 2*dx
            else:
                p = p + 2*dy
            img[y, x]=0
    else:
        p = 2*x - dy
        while y != y2:
            y = y + ys
            if p > 0:
                x = x + xs
                p = p + 2*dx - 2*dy
            else:
                p = p + 2*dx
            img[y, x]=0
            
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5, 5)
    plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 80
    
    figure, axes = plt.subplots()
    cc = plt.Circle((x, y,), 50, alpha=0.1) 
    axes.set_aspect(1) 
    axes.add_artist(cc) 
    axes.add_patch(cc)

    plt.ylim(-400, 1000)
    plt.xlim(-400, 1000)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    
def main():
    a = int(input("x1: "))
    b = int(input("y1: "))
    c = int(input("x2: "))
    d = int(input("y1: "))
    x1 = a
    y1 = b
    x2 = c
    x3 = d
    drawLine(a, b, c, d)
    
#    if __name__ == "__main__":
#        main()
        
#Create a Button to plot the graph
button= ttk.Button(win, text= "Graph", command=main)       #  - DrawLine
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: А для чего у вас круг рисуется в библиотеки `matplotlib`? А не на `canvas` в `tkinter`, где и анимацию сделать проще?

Comment: И если используете `tkinter`, почему не используете поля `entry` для ввода координат?

Comment: @СергейКох я только начинаю как мог, так и сделал, если у вас есть альтернативное решение, буду очень благодарен, если вы им поделитесь.

Comment: Можете посмотреть здесь https://younglinux.info/tkinter/canvasmeth, а так наберите - анимация ткинтер - желательно на английском языке, то найдете даже на этом сайте, много вариантов.